# missing a template for this request format and variant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails and am trying to gain a strong understanding of how MVC works.

I did the following:

```
rails new bubblesman 
rails generate controller bubble
```

in my bubble controller I created a method as follows:

```
def available
  puts "YEP!!!!!!"
end
```

I put the following in my routes file:

```
'welcome' => 'bubble#available'
```

I navigate to http://localhost:3000/welcome
I get the below error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (BubbleController#available is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []

NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not… nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.):
```

what I also don't understand is if I put this in my helper controller instead of my main controller it all works fine.

Comment: File names were fine, restarting the server helped

Answer (score 48, accepted):

you need to create the `available.html.erb` file within the `views/bubble/` directory. When the route takes you to that action, it also navigates you to that view, so if you put:

```
<h2>YEP!!!!</h2>
```

as the only line in that file, it should return that to you on the webpage.

In the future, you could use `rails g scaffold bubbles` and that will create a majority of the files (MVC) and routes for you.

Comment: Works. Thank you. If I wanted to use multiple methods in my controller does it need a new html.erb every time?

Comment: the only way I could think to make that work would be to use a redirect at the end of every controller method to point to the `available` method for showing. 

But on a basic level, yes, you'll most likely need a html.erb for most methods.

Comment: Thanks. This actually helps a ton. I have read a lot of tutorials but never really grasped this part until now.