# ActionController::UnknownFormat in PostsController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a _posts_controller.rb_:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

Then I created a *index.html.erb* file under "app/views/posts" folder:

```
<h1> Blog Post </h1>
```

Then i added the this to *routes.rb*:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/index'

  resources :posts

  root 'home#index'
end
```

I restarted the server and getting this error, when trying to access the posts index page:

```
PostsController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.
```

Comment: Hello Roshan, could you read this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?)

Comment: Yes I will do. Thanks

Comment: Can you show more of server logs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40009571/missing-a-template-for-this-request-format-and-variant

Comment: Server is starting unexpectedly:
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
Completed 406 Not acceptable in 1631ms 
(lot of lib/action_controller.... logs. I hope i could submit a screenshot here)

Comment: I actually checked this thread as well. I noted that they created available.html.erb file
whereas i created index.html.erb file in the posts folder.

Comment: Server Logs:
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:53:in `default_render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `block in send_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `tap'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:186:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'

Answer (score 0):

Right now, from your description it looks like your `root` route points to a non-existent controller.
You either need a `HomeController` with an `index` method, and a directory `app/views/home` where you place an `index.html.erb` view, or change the `root` route to point to the `'posts#index'`.

Comment: I have both Home Controller and Post Controller in the Controller file. If i run http://localhost:3000/ It works fine for Home Controller. I created a new Post Controller to try creating a Blog. While if i run this URL: http://localhost:3000/posts it gives an error

Comment: I changed the root route to 'posts#index' and it still gives the error.

Comment: Extracted source (around line #53):
51
52
53
54
55
56
              
          "That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot."

        raise ActionController::UnknownFormat, message
      else
        logger.info "No template found for #{self.class.name}\##{action_name}, rendering head :no_content" if logger
        super

Answer (score 0):

It seems `PostsController#index` the `index` file missing in `posts` folder, so create an `index.html.erb` into `views/posts/` folder

If the problem is not solving after trying many ways then not waste your time on this, you can start from scratch again because I'm guessing you are in the initial stage so don't hesitate & start from [Rails official](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) doc again & see what's happening.

Hope it will help.

Comment: I already have the index.html.erb file on views/posts/ folder. Also i changed get 'home/index', to: "home#index" but it gave me the argument missing error again. I edit the code again to get 'home/index'

Comment: Please restart the server

Comment: Same error:

PostsController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] we're showing an error to be extra-clear. 
Extracted source (around line #53)
          "That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot."
        raise ActionController::UnknownFormat, message
      else
        logger.info "No template found for #{self.class.name}\##{action_name}, rendering head :no_content" if logger
        super

Comment: Extracted source (around line #53):
51
52
53
54
55
56
              
          "That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot."

        raise ActionController::UnknownFormat, message
      else
        logger.info "No template found for #{self.class.name}\##{action_name}, rendering head :no_content" if logger
        super

Comment: Please forget about that & start from official doc http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html again & see what's happening

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments. I got the answer of my issue.

I actually created the text file under this folder "app/views/posts" and put the extension of the text file as index.html.erb

I deleted the above text file. And then i created another file in notepad++ and put the name of the file as index.html.erb
All my earlier code stayed the same and it works fine. I am glad that i found the issue so that i can move ahead for my Ruby learning :)