# get request not working in ruby on rails - 6.1.4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Rail version details**

```
ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [x64-mingw32]
```

**What did I search so far?? - None of the below helped me figure out the root cause of the issue**

[missing a template for this request format and variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40009571/missing-a-template-for-this-request-format-and-variant)

https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/kkh4zg/why_am_i_getting_this_error/

https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/action-controller-is-missing-a-template-for-request-formats/255027

After creating the application with the syntax: `rails new practise1`, I added below code in the architecture,

inside app/controller, created a new controller  about_controller.rb

```
class AboutController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end
end
```

inside views. created a new folder about and added a file index.html.erb

then, finally in config/routes.rb file added below code,

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "about", to: "about#index"
end
```

**Error Details**

[image]

Comment: do you have an html file in `app/views/about/` in your project?

Comment: inside views. created a new folder about and added a file index.html.erb

Comment: what do you get from `rake routes` or `rails routes`?

Comment: there was a large list of routes, here you go: https://i.stack.imgur.com/14Vv2.png

Comment: that looks fine. in your `rails server` does it give a specific path that the system is not finding the file?  (it might be that your directory has to be "abouts" rather than "about").  I'm also assuming that you're working in "development` mode, rather than `production`?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ECLq.png this is the route details. and here is the file explorer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj9XY.png Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 2):

Your error is saying that your template is missing.

As you created a method `index` in your controller `About`, you shall create a template in the following file : `app/views/about/index.html.erb`

You can see all the steps in the getting started of Rails :
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#say-hello-rails

---

On Windows, using PowerShell, you can have an issue with your path. Rails is **case-sensitive**, so you need to be careful of your path where you launch `rails s`.

You can see this way :

```sh
❯ echo $PWD
/Users/username/rails/myRailsApp
❯ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 24579
Loading development environment (Rails 6.1.4.1)
irb(main):001:0> ActionView::LookupContext.fallbacks
=> 
[#<ActionView::FallbackFileSystemResolver:0x00007ff320b86918
  @cache=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache:0x00007ff320b861e8 keys=0 queries=0>,
  @path="/Users/username/rails/myRailsApp",
  @path_parser=#<ActionView::Resolver::PathParser:0x00007ff320b86350>,
  @pattern=":prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:formats,}{+:variants,}{.:handlers,}",
  @unbound_templates=#<Concurrent::Map:0x00007ff320b86710 entries=0 default_proc=nil>>,
 #<ActionView::FallbackFileSystemResolver:0x00007ff320b858b0
  @cache=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache:0x00007ff320b85748 keys=0 queries=0>,
  @path="/",
  @path_parser=#<ActionView::Resolver::PathParser:0x00007ff320b85770>,
  @pattern=":prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:formats,}{+:variants,}{.:handlers,}",
  @unbound_templates=#<Concurrent::Map:0x00007ff320b85888 entries=0 default_proc=nil>>]
```

The `@path` is getting your environment `PWD` value given by your shell. And Rails will use it in order to resolve your templates files.

https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/getting-started-with-rails-no-template-for-interactive-request/76162/2

Comment: my index.html.erb which can be located in views/about folder, have this content: `<h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>` Should this not work with this content only?

Comment: The content is enough. But I think you should verrify that you created your template in the correct place.
Please try `ls app/views/about/index.html.erb`. That seems strange 
otherwise..

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ECLq.png this is the route details. and here is the file explorer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj9XY.png Am i missing anything?

Comment: What did your console says when you reload the page ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM8Hz.png, please let me know if you need more info or team viewer

Comment: Can you try this : `rails g controller About index --force` then restart `rails s` ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9pj3.png but in vain ,Same error. Please let me know if you need more info

Comment: Well, there are some ways to change the default path for the templates files. Maybe you've change this in your configuration. Please take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301249/how-to-change-the-default-path-of-view-files-in-a-rails-3-controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237150/discussion-between-emilien-baudet-and-pankaj-garg).